# Rで二項分布がデータフレームで機能しない

Tags: r

性別によって心疾患の罹患割合が違うデータを作成したいとする

```r
n <- 100
id <- 1:n
sex <- rbinom(n,1,0.6)
X <- data.frame(id,sex)
riskA <- 0.20
riskB <- 0.05
X$card <- ifelse(X$sex==1,rbinom(1,1,riskA),rbinom(1,1,riskB))
summary(X$card)
```

とすると、なぜか全てゼロになります。

なぜでしょうか？
どうすれば作成できるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rbinom(1,1,riskA) ではなく rbinom(n,1,riskA) のようにすると
うまくいくと思います。

```
library(tidyverse)
X$card <- ifelse(X$sex==1,rbinom(n,1,riskA),rbinom(n,1,riskB))
summary(X$card)
X %>%
    group_by(sex) %>%
    summarise(M = mean(card))
```

で確かめて下さい。

以下の説明は伝わりにくいかもしれません。
rbinomの最初の引数は返す乱数の個数です。
なので1にすると X$sex==0 と X$sex==1 の場合とで
それぞれ固定された数（rbinom(1,1,riskA)の返り値とrbinom(1,1,riskB)の返り値）
がX$cardに代入されることになります。

rbinom(n,1,riskA)およびrbinom(n,1,riskB)の場合には
それぞれ作成されたn個の乱数からsexに応じて値が選ばれます。

また、今回の場合
riskA <- 0.20
riskB <- 0.05
と1を返す確率が小さいため0となりやすいため
すべて0となったものと考えられます。

Comment: できました、ありがとうございます！